# Random image code inside animation swift code

Tags: ios, swift, animation, random, swift2

I have tried several codes I have found here (stackoverflow) and on web, but no one of them worked.

Can you please help?

This is code:

```
        import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var UmagGlavna: UIImageView!

let images = [
    UIImage(named: "UmagGlavna1")!,
    UIImage(named: "UmagGlavna2")!,
    UIImage(named: "UmagGlavna3")!]

var index = 0
let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.4
let switchingInterval: NSTimeInterval = 5

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UmagGlavna.image = images[index]
    index += 1
    animateImageView()
}

func animateImageView() {
    CATransaction.begin()

    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(self.switchingInterval * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.animateImageView()
        }
    }

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    /*
     transition.type = kCATransitionPush
     transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
     */
    UmagGlavna.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    UmagGlavna.image = images[index]

    CATransaction.commit()

    index = index < images.count - 1 ? index + 1 : 0
}
```

}

I have try to insert this line in func viewDidLoad

```
UmagGlavna.image = UIImage(named: "UmagGlavna\(arc4random_uniform(3) + 1)")
```

then I have also try to insert several other codes, this one was one of them:

```
        @IBAction func randomimage(sender: AnyObject) {
//list of Images in array 
let image : NSArray = [
    UIImage(named: "UmagGlavna1")!,
    UIImage(named: "UmagGlavna2")!,
    UIImage(named: "UmagGlavna3")!]

//random image generating method
let imagerange: UInt32 = UInt32(images.count)
let randomimage = Int(arc4random_uniform(imagerange))
let generatedimage: AnyObject = images.objectAtIndex(randomimage)
self.myimage.image = generatedimage as? UIImage
```

}

And some other codes, but nothing has made images load random.

What I need is to first image load (or all images) random, because when you start app, I don't wont always to load with same (first) image.

Thank is advance for help. :)

Comment: You posted a bunch of somebody else's code that it's clear you don't understand, but it is not clear what you are trying to do. You need to write a clear, coherent description of what you want to do. Are you talking about the launch screen? If so, I don't think you can load a random image in the launch screen storyboard.

Comment: I am sorry for unclear description.

No, this is not launch screen, this is main storyboard.

I am trying to do this:

When you enter app, first you see on top of the screen is image gallery with several images transition (animated - fade in and fate out) trough each other.

What I would like to do is that in this gallery first image is not the same, in this case is image with name "UmagGlavna1". I would like every time you enter into app, that first image is not the same, but random. :)

Comment: So you want to switch between the same 3 images, but in different order? Or you only want the first image to change, but the rest of the images to always be the same?

Comment: Thanks Duncan for answer. :)

Well, both is good. My primary objective is that first image is not always the same, but maybe it is better to randomize whole thing and when user enter app, that every time images are in different order.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your code to start by selecting one of your images randomly, then cycle through the others, change your viewDidLoad code to set index to a random value:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Select a random image index to start with 
    index = arc4random_uniform(images.count) //This is the new line to add.

    UmagGlavna.image = images[index]
    index += 1
    animateImageView()
}
```

You'll probably need some type casting to get that line to compile without errors. I'll leave it to you to work that out.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I have used similar code, I have inserted it in new "asnswer". :)

Answer (score 0):

This is code that I have used:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    index = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    UmagGlavna.image = images[index]
    index += 1
    animateImageView()
}
```

I think this is OK for now, maybe it wont be sufficient latter and I must test it with more images, but this works for now.

Comment: I would suggest against using the constant value 2. If you use images.count in your call to arc4random_uniform then if later you decide to put more images in your array, it just works.

Comment: Why post a second answer that uses code that is all but identical to my solution, but post it a day later?

Comment: Sorry Duncan, but I am new in Swift. I am still learning and your code gave me error, so I changed in one I posted.

I think your is better, but this one gave me no error and I know I must be aware to change number in Int after adding more images.

This app is very simple, but working on it I am learning and sharpening my skills :D ;)

Comment: No, don't use a constant number 2, and then go back and change it if you add additional images. My point is that you should write your code to ask the array how many items it has and generate a random index based on the number of elements. That way the code will work for ANY number of elements. Using a constant value creates a future code maintenance and debugging problem.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll listen to you... :)
Back to project. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are trying to sharpen your skills then this is a teaching moment. Hard-coding a constant that will be wrong as soon as anything changes is a bad idea. Since your code deals with an array "images", it's much, MUCH better to make it ask the array how many elements it contains and automatically generate a random number that spans the whole range of indexes.